# Codigo para generar una vuelta al juego python

Tags: python

soy bastante novato en programacion y necesito ayuda con el siguiente codigo:

```
def introduccion():
    print("hola que tal")

def elige():
    elige=int(input("introduce un numero: "))
    if elige== int(1):
        print("+100ptos")
    elif elige==int(2):
        print("0pts")


def a():
    print(input("introduce si quieres volveer: "))


volver=("si")
for i in volver:
    while volver==("si") or volver==("s"):
        introduccion()
        elige()
        a()
introduccion()
elige()
a()
```

como veis he creado el siguiente codigo en el que si pones el numero 1 te imprime 100 ptos y si pones el numero 2 te da 0 ptos. Mi problema ahora es como hago para que una vez que ingrese el numero 1 o 2 y me de los puntos me pregunte si quiero volver a empezar. El codigo que he escrito solamente me dice si quiero volver a empezar y le meto cualquier cosa y siempre vuelve a empezar independientemente de que le diga que "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veo que tienes varios problemas aquí. Te detallo a continuación:

En esta primera parte todo bien, creas dos funciones; una para saludar y otra para asignar los puntos.

```
def introduccion():
    print("hola que tal")

def elige():
    elige=int(input("introduce un numero: "))
    if elige== int(1):
        print("+100ptos")
    elif elige==int(2):
        print("0pts")
```

En la función `a()` hay un problema, porque le esta pidiendo al usuario que ingrese si quiere volver a realizar la asignación, y directamente imprimiendo ese valor. No estás guardando esa respuesta en una variable, para posteriormente ser usada.

```
def a():
    print(input("introduce si quieres volveer: "))
```

Ahora, en esta parte lo que haces es asignarle directamente el valor `"si"` a volver. Y después creas un bucle **for** para recorrer letra por letra ese `"si"`. Es decir, los valor de `i` van a ser, en la primera vuelta, `"s"`, y en la segunda vuelta, `"i"`. Así que eso no tiene mucho sentido. Además tampoco estás usando esa variable `i`. Después agregas un bucle `while` que siempre se va a repetir porque, como mencioné antes, `volver` es igual a `"si"`, por lo tanto, siempre va a entrar en el bucle, por más que pongas otra respuesta. Una vez que entra al bucle `while` ya no va a salir de ahí, a no ser que detengas el programa forzosamente.

```
volver=("si")
for i in volver:
    while volver==("si") or volver==("s"):
        introduccion()
        elige()
        a()
```

Entonces, **¿Cómo se soluciona esto?**

Lo que hice aquí fue colocar todo dentro de la función `a()` y le asigné la respuesta del usuario a la variable `volver`. Ahora, si `volver` es igual a `"si"` o `"s"` entrará en el bucle, inmediatamente se limpia la variable por si el usuario decide salir del programa. De esa manera, cada vez que pregunte, `volver` toma el valor, evalúa la respuesta para entrar al `while`, y se limpia a 0. Para que no mantenga el valor `"si"` anteriormente asignado y no entre en un bucle infinito.

```
def a():
    volver=input("introduce si quieres volveer: ")
    while volver=="si" or volver=="s":
        volver=0
        introduccion()
        elige()
        a()
```

#### Observaciones:

Si ya declaraste una variable como entero, no tiene mucho sentido que la compares si es entero otra vez. Por eso, le quité el `int()` de los **if** en la función `elige()`.

No hace falta usar paréntesis para usar un `string`; en realidad, da la impresión de que es una tupla de un sólo elemento.

### Código completo:

```
def introduccion():
    print("hola que tal")

def elige():
    elige=int(input("introduce un numero: "))
    if elige == 1:
        print("+100ptos")
    elif elige == 2:
        print("0pts")

def a():
    volver=input("introduce si quieres volveer: ")
    while volver=="si" or volver=="s":
        volver=0
        introduccion()
        elige()
        a()

introduccion()
elige()
a()
```

Comment: Respecto al apartado de la función elige() como quedaria si quisiera crear una variable que almacene los puntos que va ganado, es decir que si en una primera ronda gana 100 ptos y en la siguiente vuelve a ganar 100 ptos mas como podria hacer para que llevara un contador con los puntos. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Para eso inicializas una variable, por ejemplo `puntos`, y cuando entre al `if elige==1:` colocas `puntos=puntos+100`, de esa manera, se irá acumulando cada vez que entre. _Para más información sobre acumuladores puedes ver este artículo:_ [https://medium.com/10-goto-10/algoritmos-variables-contadores-y-acumuladores-6d8f7d1bfbc7]

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que antes del bucle for estableces la variable volver a "si" y luego dentro del buble while no le cambias el valor a dicha variable, creo tendría que ser así:

```
volver=("si")
for i in volver:
    while volver==("si") or volver==("s"):
       introduccion()
       elige()
       volver = a()
```